# Is there a limit on how many arguments can be passed to .render()? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

The reason I ask is that when I only have 1 argument in my `render()` it seems to work just fine but when I add a 2nd, it throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`.

This is my code:

**create.ejs [JS]**

```
if (url.indexOf('?alert') != -1) {
    Alert.render('Record has been created!', 'Create');
}
```

**customAlert.js**

```
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
function CustomAlert() {
    this.render = function(body, head) {
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogOverlay = document.getElementById('dialogOverlay');
        var dialogBox = document.getElementById('dialogBox');

        dialogOverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogBox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * 0.5) +"px";
        dialogBox.style.top = "200px";
        dialogBox.style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById('dialogBoxHead').innerHTML = head;
        document.getElementById('dialogBoxBody').innerHTML = body;
        document.getElementById('dialogBoxFoot').innerHTML = '<button    id="customBtn" onclick="Alert.ok(' + JSON.stringify(head) + ')">OK</button>';
    };
    this.ok = function(selected){
        document.getElementById('dialogBox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogOverlay').style.display = "none";
        if (selected != 'Oops!') {
            location.replace("http://localhost:3000/software");
        } else {
            location.replace("http://localhost:3000/home");
        }
    };
}
```

It throws the Exception on `create:2` which is just a `<html>` tag?
Any idea as to why this is happening?
It is also worth mentioning that I have another custom alert called `customDelete.js` which works as intended but only passes 1 argument to it's `render()`

Comment: There is no limit to how many arguments can be passed to *any* JavaScript function.

Comment: Then I am struggling to understand what the issue is here and why it will work with 1 argument but not with 2

Comment: If it says "syntax error", then the issue is a syntax error, not a limit on how many arguments a function can accept. You are looking in the wrong direction.